# Integrate Laravel into Wordpress and header's dropdown menu is not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, laravel

I use laravel to integrate wordpress.

And have already require 'wp-load.php' yet.

I create a view like this

```
{!! get_header() !!}
```

There html and css is working fine.

But dropdown menu is not working.

By the way I use astra theme to create that.